# Select with options MYSQL PHP Update

Tags: php, mysql, select, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a column that manage if a project is open or locked. This is column is enum with 0 and 1. I need help to update this column to correct value.

**Here is my check for option list.**

```
$stripped = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$getModul = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_moduler WHERE locked = '0' AND id = '$stripped'"); 
    if($modulsinfo = mysql_fetch_array($getModul))      
           {    
            echo'
                <div class="form-group" style="width:60%;">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option selected>Open</option>
                        <option name="status" id="status" value="status">Locked</option>                
                    </select>
                </div>';
           }
    else 
           {
                echo'                   
                    <div class="form-group" style="width:60%;">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option name="status1" id="status1" value="status1">Open</option>
                            <option selected>Locked</option>
                        </select>
                   </div>';
          {

 }}}
 ?>
```

1. I can't figure out how to insert the selected option.
2. How can I convert "open" AND "locked" to 1 or 0.

**Here is my insert so far:**

```
$stripped = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$mytextarea = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mytextarea']);
$image = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['image']);
$status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
$status1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status1']);

if(isset($_POST['moduledit']))
{

    if (empty($_POST['title']))
    {
        echo    '<div class="alert bg-danger" role="alert">
                    <svg class="glyph stroked cancel"><use xlink:href="#stroked-cancel"></use></svg> Tittel mangler på modulen.</span></a>
                </div>';
    }

else {
       if (empty($_POST['mytextarea']))
            {
                echo '<div class="alert bg-danger" role="alert">
                        <svg class="glyph stroked cancel"><use xlink:href="#stroked-cancel"></use></svg> Modulen kan ikke være tom.</span></a>
                    </div>';
            }   

        else 
            {   

                $result = mysql_query("UPDATE cms_moduler SET locked = '$status' OR '$status1', image = '$image', title = '$title', longstory = '$mytextarea' WHERE id = $stripped;");
            }
```

Comment: Sidenote: `UPDATE/SET` does not use `OR` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html - So `SET locked = '$status' OR '$status1'` is failing here and checking for errors with `mysql_error()` on the query would have thrown you a syntax error about it.

Comment: Plus, where are the named inputs for all the POST arrays including the `<form></form>` itself?

Comment: Then I see `$_POST['image']` which suggests file handling and if so, then you need to use `$_FILES` and a post method with a valid enctype, which are unknownst to us.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove this `locked = '0'` condition from the `WHERE` clause, otherwise the `SELECT` query will fetch only the open projects. So your `SELECT` query should be like this:

```
// your code
$getModul = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_moduler WHERE id = '$stripped'");
```

Second, instead of creating two different `div`s, create only one `div` to show whether the fetched project is in `open` or `locked` state, like this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($getModul)){
    $modulsinfo = mysql_fetch_array($getModul); 
    ?>
    <div class="form-group" style="width:60%;">
        <select class="form-control" name="status">
            <option<?php if($modulsinfo['locked'] == 0){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> value='0'>Open</option>
            <option<?php if($modulsinfo['locked'] == 1){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> value='1'>Locked</option>        
        </select>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Finally after form submission, simply use `$_POST['status']` to get the status of project i.e. `0` for `open` and `1` for `locked`, like this:

```
// your code
// $status would be either 0 or 1
$status = mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_POST['status']);

// Now perform your UPDATE operation
```

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_` database extensions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and are removeda altogether in PHP 7.0.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) driver instead. And this is [why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Have a look at [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927379/select-with-options-mysql-php-update#comment67139072_39927379) I left under the question ;-) that's what's the biggest thing which is failing them and possibly more that we don't know about, as said under my 2nd and 3rd comments.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah, I had noticed that `locked = '$status' OR '$status1'`. I assumed that OP is confused about what to put in there, that's why `locked = '$status' OR '$status1'` thingy. I'm actually waiting for any update from the OP.

Comment: No idea where the guy is, so wishing you well with this ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- OP might have gone for a good night sleep after posting the question. ;-)